# How to make a loop to ctrl+f every value in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro to insert a new column after the last occupied column in a sheet, then search for the column title "Part Number" in my example and Ctrl+F search for each string listed in the column, and search for it in another workbook. If the string is found in that workbook, I want "Found in 'Workbook Name'" to be filled in the same row as the part number it just searched for but the column that was created at the beginning. This is a part of a larger function so I am passing all the variables in including what's being searched for 'colTitle1', the book and sheet the values are on, 'BOM', the sheet "BOMSheet", and the document being searched 'SearchDoc".

The main function is here:

```
Public Sub OCCLCheck(colTitle As String, BOM As Workbook, BOMSheet As Worksheet)

Dim OCCL As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim pn As Variant
Dim lastRow As Integer

'Counts number of rows in Column A with content
lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))


'Flashy but not good for regular use - uncomment when not showing off product
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Code for user to indicate the OCCL doc with a file path box - add something to prompt again if cancelled
OCCL = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose OCCL File", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If OCCL <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(OCCL)
        'OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:E20").Copy
    End If

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Call SearchFunc("Part Number", BOM, BOMSheet, OCCL)

End Sub
```

The search function is here:

```
Public Sub SearchFunc(colTitle1 As String, BOM As Workbook, BOMSheet As Worksheet, SearchDoc As Workbook)

Dim pn As String
Dim colTitle2 As String
Dim c As Variant
Dim lastRow As Integer
'Code to search for something on something else, made for searching across books

'Find the column with colTitle1
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .find(colTitle1, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        pn = ActiveSheet.Range(c.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
End With

'Count number of rows to iterate search through
lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

        For i = 1 To lastRow

        If Cells.find(What:=Workbooks(BOM).Worksheets(BOMSheet).Range(i, 2).Value, After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=Workbooks(SearchDoc).Worksheets(1).xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate <> .Range(i, 2).Value Then 'Write not on occl to first unoccupied column also add code to find unoccupied column before this loop
        End If

End Sub
```

I am pretty lost at where to go now as I know what I want to do but I am new to VBA so getting the program to do it is my problem ATM, any suggestions are appreciated!

[image: Before]

[image: Final Product]

This is the error with the macro searching for const "Part Number"
[[image: Error Message][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7lLw.png)

Comment: And which is your problem? Does the code return an error? If yes, what error and on witch row? If not, what the code problem is? It will be interesting to show us what you have, what do you want and what do you obtain using this code. Editable will be the best, but even some pictures would help, I think...

Comment: I only have up until the find command written. I need to still make a section that finds the next open column, assigns that to a variable so when something is found in the other sheet it can fill that row and column with the result, then iterate it over all the parts on the sheet.

Comment: Sample data may help here (what you have & what you want)

Comment: Until now you only try to explain what you want, even if I (for instance) do not understand too much... Since you posted some code, it is normal to explain us what bothers you in using it. If we do not know what you intend to do, it is very difficult to deduce what problems  it (maybe) creates... Is it so difficult to post some images (preferable editable) us I previously suggested? What you have, what you want and what your code produces?

Comment: Ok I added the before and after goal. I want it to add the column where there was nothing and I want it to use Cells.find method. The pictures aren't representative of position and how spread out the data will be so VLOOKUP doesn't work unfortunately or I would just make the code write that in

Comment: Did I do it wrong? I thought I put in 2 images at the bottom...

Comment: How big are these workbooks, approx. number of rows in each ?

Comment: they vary a lot the most is about 15k, the average is probably around 1500

Comment: Do you want all the sheets in the workbook searched or just the first one  wb.sheets(1) ?

Comment: All the sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the essential parts needed to build your solution should be within this script. I used xlWhole in the Find so that ABC1 would not match ABC10 but if part numbers are fixed length maybe xlPart is OK.  Refactor into smaller subs and functions as necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Sub macro()

    Const COL_TITLE = "Part Number"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, found As Range
    Dim wbSearch As Workbook, wsSearch As Worksheet

    Dim rng As Range, iResultCol As Integer, iPartCol As Integer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("BOM D6480000005")

    ' headers
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Rows(1)

    ' determine part number col
    Set found = rng.Find(COL_TITLE, , xlValues, xlPart)
    If found Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Can't find " & COL_TITLE, vbCritical, "Search failed"
      Exit Sub
    End If
    iPartCol = found.Column

    ' determine last col
    iResultCol = rng.Columns.count + rng.Column
    ws.Cells(1, iResultCol) = "Search Result"
    Debug.Print rng.Address, iPartCol, iResultCol

    Dim sFilename As String
    sFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose OCCL File", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If Len(sFilename) > 0 Then
       Set wbSearch = Application.Workbooks.Open(sFilename)
    Else
       MsgBox "No file chosen", vbExclamation
       Exit Sub
    End If

    ' find last row
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long, sPartNo As String, count As Long
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, iPartCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print "iLastRow", iLastRow

    ' search each sheet
    For Each wsSearch In wbSearch.Sheets
        For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
            sPartNo = ws.Cells(iRow, iPartCol)
            If Len(sPartNo) > 0 Then
                Set found = wsSearch.UsedRange.Find(sPartNo, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                If found Is Nothing Then
                ' not found
                Else
                    ws.Cells(iRow, iResultCol) = "Found in " & wbSearch.Name & _
                    " " & wsSearch.Name & _
                    " at " & found.Address

                    count = count + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' end
    wbSearch.Close False
    MsgBox count & " matches", vbInformation, "Finished"

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good as far as I can tell but I have a few things that aren't working. The function won't find Part Number and is giving the error message you wrote in and search is failing. I am adding in the picture of the error and sheet to the main Q

Comment: @Shawn Which sheet and row  is 'Part Number' on ?. You could skip that bit for now and set it yourself iPartCol =  2 'found.Column and comment out the exit sub . See if the rest works.

Comment: The code runs but the result is 0 matches. There should be 10 I think. Not sure of the exact number but there are matches that should be found. Running through with F8  it is outputting ```$A$1           2             2 
iLastRow       1 
$B$1           2             3 
iLastRow       1 
$B$1:$C$1      2             4``` in the active window, it looks like it is only recognizing 3 rows?

Comment: Step in seems to skip the entire search and match process, In the final segment it skips from `For Each wsSearch` line to `wbSearch.Close` None of the loops run it looks like.

Comment: The macro is in the personal workbook I plan to use it across many different books once it is all finished. The macro is being used in the same book that the part numbers are in yes. The cell with "Part Number" is B1 or range(1,2). The part numbers are directly below that starting in B2 and until B5351.

Comment: The goal of making this part is to make everything a variable so I can search another column as well after the "Part Number" column, then use this function call to search another type of sheet, then another. One step at a time though.

Comment: BOM D6480000005 Sorry about that

Comment: @Shawn OK, I've updated the code, you shouldn't have to make any changes. Just run it as a standalone script. Hopefully it will find the Part Number column

Comment: Sorry,  I would bring this to chat but I don't have the rep. The `ws = wb.Sheets("BOM D6480000005")` is the error now. I even tried to copy and paste the name of the sheet into the code but no good. Runtime Error '9': Out of range

Comment: @shawn Try putting the macro on that sheet and run it from there.

Comment: That worked!  It fills the cell in the open column with the output!